# Handling global namespaces in lxml parsing functions

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm dealing with some XML documents that share a custom namespace. I have a variety of different kinds of files with the same namespace and am trying to figure out the best/most elegant way of handling the namespaces when parsing. Here's an example:

At the beginning of a particular script, I read in an XML file, parse it with `etree.parse()`, inspect the first tag or two to identify the namespaces, and then I save them somewhere. I could put them in a global but for now they're stored at the class level as `self.ns`.

I have this function I wrote for returning values from a given xpath query. It looks like this:

```
# noinspection PyBroadException
def get_value(self, lxml_object, xpath_query=None, return_int=False):
    """
    BE CAREFUL using this function because it will catch all xpath query exceptions
    :param lxml_object: an lxml.etree object
    :param xpath_query: a valid xpath query
    :param return_int: set to True if you want an int rather than a string
    :return: the value of the field corresponding to the xpath query
    """
    if return_int is True:
        if xpath_query:
            try:
                return int(lxml_object.xpath(xpath_query, namespaces=self.ns)[0].text)
            except:
                return None
        else:
            try:
                return int(lxml_object[0].text)
            except:
                return None
    else:
        if xpath_query:
            try:
                return lxml_object.xpath(xpath_query, namespaces=self.ns)[0].text
            except:
                return None
        else:
            try:
                return lxml_object[0].text
            except:
                return None
```

This is fine when I put it inside my class and call `self.get_value()` because `self.ns` is already defined.

I use this function in a lot of different scripts and want to put it in a separate file for parsing utilities, from which I could just import it. However, that raises the specter of adding a namespaces argument to it and having to pass the namespaces to the function each time I use it, like

`return get_value(some_lxml_object, 'some xpath query', ns=self.ns)`

How can I structure all this if I don't want to have to pass a namespaces argument each time I call the function?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is "partially apply the function".

```
def build_value_getter(namespace):
    def func(some_lxml_object, 'some xpath query', ns=namespace)
        return get_value(some_lxml_object, 'some xpath query', ns=ns)
    return func

my_get_value = build_value_getter(self.ns)
my_get_value(some_lxml_object, 'some xpath query') # Uses self.ns implicitly
```